# Matrix polynomial - is there a trick?

Tags: matrices, polynomials

Is there a trick for easily solving a matrix polynomial like
$$
p(A) = \left( 7\cdot A^4 - 4\cdot A^3 + 6\cdot A - 5\cdot E \right)
, A = \left(\begin{matrix}2 & -1 \\ 3 & 5\end{matrix}\right)
$$
or is it really just step-by-step calculation of
$$
7\cdot A\cdot A\cdot A\cdot A\cdot A\cdot A\cdot A-4\cdot A\cdot A\cdot A+6\cdot A-5\cdot E
$$

Comment: Do you know about diagonalizability or Jordan Normal Form?

Comment: Yes, but it does not make it much easier for me. Of course it would drasticly reduce the number of multiplications for larger matrices, but I hoped, that there would be a better way than step-by-step multiplication.

Comment: What about the characteristic polynomial, do you know of that? If so, reduce your equation by subtracting $A^ny(A)=0$ until it is of a simpler form. This works since $y(A)=0$ is the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: $( 7A^4 - 4A^3 + 6A - 5E ) = -5E + A(6E-A^2(-4E + 7A))$

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner's_method

Comment: I have to confess, I know little about the usage of the characteristic polynomial. But thanks for the hint, I am going to read a bit more about it first and come back to your suggestion later. As far as I know it is only defined for $NxN$ matrices, am I right?
**edit:** For a second I forgot, that only $NxN$ matrices can be squared. Thanks for reminding!

Comment: You can't compute powers of non-square matrices, so even though the answer to your question in the comment above this is yes, it is the best you can hope for.

Comment: Correct, as it uses powers of the matrix, and a strictly rectangular matrix cannot be squared since the dimensions do not match.

Comment: Thank you, Jan Dvorak! Horner's method was the first thing which came to my mind, but I did not realize it would work with matrices!

Comment: @Jen-Ya you only need associativity, commutativity of addition and distributivity to prove the Horner's schema. All three apply to matrices. Only the last one here is non-trivial to prove.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
  A &= \left(\begin{matrix}2 & -1 \\ 3 & 5\end{matrix}\right)
\end{align}

$$\det(A) = 2*5 - (-1)*3 = 13$$
$$\operatorname{trace}(A) = 2 + 5 = 7$$
$$y(x) = x^2 - 7x + 13$$
\begin{align}
y(A) &= \left(\begin{matrix}2 & -1 \\ 3 & 5\end{matrix}\right)^2 - 7\left(\begin{matrix}2 & -1 \\ 3 & 5\end{matrix}\right) +\left(\begin{matrix}13 & 0 \\ 0 & 13\end{matrix}\right) \\
&= \left(\begin{matrix}1 & -7 \\ 21 & 22\end{matrix}\right) - \left(\begin{matrix}14 & -7 \\ 21 & 35\end{matrix}\right) +\left(\begin{matrix}13 & 0 \\ 0 & 13\end{matrix}\right) \\
\\
&= \left(\begin{matrix}0& 0 \\ 0& 0\end{matrix}\right) \\
\end{align}
\begin{align}
  p(A) &= & 7A^4 &- 4A^3 & +0A^2 &+6A &- 5E  \\
       && - 7(A^4 & -7A^3 &+ 13A^2 &+ 0 & + 0 ) \\
      &= &  0A^4 & + 45A^3 & \overbrace{-7*13}^{-91}A^2 &+6A &- 5E \\
       &&& - 45( A^3 & -7A^2 &+ 13A & + 0 ) \\
      &=& & 0A^3 & (-91+45*7)A^2 & +(6-45*13)A & - 5E \\
      &=& &  & 224A^2 & -579A & - 5E \\
\end{align}

If my calculations were correct,
$$p(A) = 224A^2 - 579A - 5E$$

Comment: Or apply one more time to get $p(A) = 989A - 2912I - 5E$

Comment: My impression is that E is the identity matrix. [Some books use U or E](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_matrix) meaning "Unit matrix" and "Elementary matrix".

Comment: Yes, E was meant to be the "Unit matrix" or "Elementary Matrix"! Sorry if it was not clear!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ $ Since $A$ is a root of its characteristic polynomial $q(A),$ we can compute modulo $q(A)$. Here $q(x) = x^2\! - ({\rm tr}\, A)\, x +\, {\rm det}\, A = \color{#0A0}{x^2\! - 7 x + 13}.\ $ Dividing $p(x)$ by $q(x)$ by the Division Algorithm

$$ p(x)\, =\, 7 x^4\! - 4 x^3\! + 6 x - 5\, =\, (7 x^2\! + 45 x + 224)\, (\color{#0A0}{x^2\! - 7x + 13})\, +\, \color{#C00}{989 x - 2917}$$

Hence $\ p(A)\, =\, \color{#C00}{989 A - 2917\, I}\, =\, \left[\begin{array}{rr} -939 & -3906 \\ 50 & 2028 \end{array}\right]\ $ by $\ \color{#0A0}{ A^2 - 7A + 13\, I =\, 0}$

**Remark** $\ $ We don't actually need to compute the quotient - just the remainder. One simple way to compute it is to evaluate the Horner form $q(x) = -5 + x(6 + x(x(-4 + 7x)))$ from innermost-out, using the rewrite rule $\,x^2 \to 7x-13\,$ to keep the partial result of degree $\le 1$. E.g., computing the innermost term we have $\, x(-4+ 7x) = -4x+7x^2 = -4x + 7(7x-13) = 45x-91.$